# Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'NSString * _Nullable' is disallowed with ARC. incompatible integer to pointer conversion

Tags: objective-c

I'm having a issue where I try to make a label(labelchange2) text equal the integer(int) //and I get the error:

> Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'NSString * _Nullable' is disallowed with ARC

and the warning:

> Incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'NSString * _Nullable' from 'int'

Even after I switch it to be a NSString it gives me even more errors.

This is Objective-C for iOS development.

Code:

```
#import "ViewControllerTV.h"

@interface ViewControllerTV ()

@end

int x = 0;

@implementation ViewControllerTV

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.labelchange2.text = x;  // <- error here
}

- (IBAction)up2:(id)sender {
    NSString *printer3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",x ];
    self.labelchange2.text = printer3;

    x++;
}

- (IBAction)down2:(id)sender {
    NSString *printer3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",x];
    self.labelchange2.text = printer3;

    x--;
}

@end
```

Update I changed it from the “x” to

```
Self.labelchange2.text = @“0”;
```

And it fixed its self as well

Comment: Your `up2` and `down2` methods have the correct code for setting the label's text. Do the same in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding, I'm trying to get my label to equal the value x in turn equalling to 0. the buttons are supposed to change the value x either up 1 or down 1. and when I try to get x to determine the labels value it throws errors      I'm sorry if I'm being a pain lol I'm just new to objective c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the problematic line in `viewDidLoad` with:

```
self.labelchange2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",x];
```

Comment: right but the problem lies with the code changing the label to 0.

Comment: @jbiser361 This fixes the problem you have in `viewDidLoad`.